# Change permission from settings and reopen back the app

Tags: android, android-permissions

Change permission from settings and reopen back the app, in this case is there any way to get the callback to do some action.

I already added the action in onResume but even

> I press home button -> open other app -> come back it will ask for the
>   permission

. I don't want this.

**FOR EXAMPLE :** iOS restart the app if the permission changed from settings, but android does not but does android provide any callback to handle this?

Comment: You have to check permission granted from  your app, if you request app from the app, then the result will be on `onRequestPermissionsResult`

Comment: It's not about granting the permission from app it's from the settings. I already deny from the app but go to settings and trun on back, then come back to the app, If you change it from the settings onRequestPermissionsResult never called.

Comment: it just simply restart the app

Comment: in case you changed permission from settings in android , OS restart app too

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh Based one which event I should restart ?

Comment: yes, it will be

Comment: OS will automatically do that

Comment: @NehaRathore no It does't I tried. How did you tried?

Comment: which device you are using

Comment: @NehaRathore Nexsus 6P, Samsung S7

Comment: I have the same problem!
All initialization takes place on the boot screen.
After I am on the working screen, change the resolution through the settings, the application restarts bypassing the loading screen and all initialization disappears.
Is there a way to COMPLETELY restart the app?
I DO NOT HAVE TO START FROM THE CURRENT SCREEN, I need to COMPLETELY restart the application from start to finish.